# Currency Formatting in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to all of this and I couldn't find an answer worded this way when searching. I have a database with currency in it, in mysql it doesn't allow me to format the field to be in currency.  Is there a way in PHP to format the field to format the text into a currency format so it looked like $5,250,000 instead of 5250000.

```
Print "<td><center>".$row['ContractM']."</centre></td> ";}
```

Above is the line that I want to be in currency format, how would I go about formatting it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can have a look http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here. You can do this:

```
$unitcost=number_format($row['ContractM']); /* Format Number */

Print "<td><center>$ ".$unitcost."</centre></td> "; /* Echo result */
```

If you want to include cents (two decimal places after the whole number):

```
$unitcost=number_format($row['ContractM'],2); /* Format Number with decimal point */

Print "<td><center>$ ".$unitcost."</centre></td> "; /* Echo result */
```

Better also if you declare your *ContractM* row in your table as **INT** or **DOUBLE**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

or the simpler number_format() function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
echo number_format($row['ContractM'], 2, ",", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql can store the data as a string or a float. When you want to display that data you can format it as currency.

```
string money_format ( string $format , float $number )
```

money_format() returns a formatted version of number. This function wraps the C library function strfmon(), with the difference that this implementation converts only one number at a time.

Answer (score 0):

why should not you use something like, It is so simple

```
$currencyFormat='$';

<td><center>".$currencyFormat.$row['ContractM']."</centre></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change to currency in MySQL, format the number with comma style, concat that with dollar sign, and replace '$-' with '-$' to deal with negative numbers.

```
Select replace(concat('$', format(number,0)), '$-', '-$') as currency
```